# Method that has a hash, and a proc arguments not running

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

I am not sure why this method is not running.

The compile error reads:

```
sequence5.rb:1:in `sequence5': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError) from sequence5.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

But as you can see clearly, `sequence5` method should take 2 arguments, one for `args` hash and the other for `b` proc.

The code I'm trying to run is here.

```rb
def sequence5(args, &b)
  n, m, c = args[:n], args[:m], args[:c]
  i = 0
  while i < n
    b.call(i*m+c)
    i += 1
  end
end

p = Proc.new {|x| puts x}
sequence5({:n=>3, :m=>4, :c=>0}, p)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sequence5({:n=>3, :m=>4, :c=>0}, &p)
```

p is not an argument, it's a block and Ruby has different syntax for passing a block